# ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, jquery, requirejs-config.js

I created a countdown using JS. For that i need jQuery so I created requireJs file.

```
var config = {
paths: {
    'countDown': "ABC_CoundDown/js/countDown"
},
shim: {
    'countDown': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
};
```

then added jquery in **web/js/jquery.js**

then in phtml I used

```
<script type="text/javascript">

require([
    'jquery',
    'countDown',
    'domReady'
    ], function(
    $,
) {
    var date = "2019-02-12";
    var myDate = new Date(date);
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 2);
    $("#countdown").countdown(myDate, function (event) {
        $(this).html(
            event.strftime(
                '<div class="timer-wrapper"><div class="time">%D</div><span class="text">days</span></div><div class="timer-wrapper"><div class="time">%H</div><span class="text">hrs</span></div><div class="timer-wrapper"><div class="time">%M</div><span class="text">mins</span></div><div class="timer-wrapper"><div class="time">%S</div><span class="text">sec</span></div>'
            )
        );
    });

});
```

on frontend I'm getting this error instead of my result
[image]

Comment: use jQuery instead of $

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the js code. Remove the `,` after `$` in `function($,)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have typo issue in your code so Please replace your code with this and let me know if any issue.

```
 require(['jquery','countDown','domReady'], function(jQuery) {
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var date = "2019-02-12";
    var myDate = new Date(date);
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 2);
    jQuery("#countdown").countdown(myDate, function (event) {
        jQuery(this).html(
            event.strftime('<div class="timer-wrapper"><div class="time">%D</div><span class="text">days</span></div><div class="timer-wrapper"><div class="time">%H</div><span class="text">hrs</span></div><div class="timer-wrapper"><div class="time">%M</div><span class="text">mins</span></div><div class="timer-wrapper"><div class="time">%S</div><span class="text">sec</span></div>');
        );
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: still same error.

Comment: can you try to add $(document).ready(function() and check it again ? pelase check my updated code for more information

Comment: after using your updated code 

TypeError: $ is undefined[Learn More] countDown.js:221:5
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Learn More]

Comment: did you call countDown.js in your requirejs-config.js file ?

Comment: yes, check in question, i have added my files in question,

Comment: Ohh I see, let me check code again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89611/discussion-between-aasim-goriya-and-i-ali).